# Изменение цвета всех линий при нажатии на кнопку Undo

Tags: java, android, canvas, color

Разбираюсь с рисованием. По готовому примеру сделал приложение, в котором можно рисовать разными цветами.
По [другому примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075560/undo-button-in-android-drawing-app) добавил кнопку отменить последнее нарисованное.
Проблема заключается в том, что при выборе другого цвета изменяется цвет всех ранее нарисованнных линий на выбранный. Если не использовать undo, то с цветами все хорошо.

Вот мой код:

DrawingView.java:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Path drawPath;
    private boolean erase=false;
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    private ArrayList<Path> moveList =  new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undoList =  new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Path> currentMoveList =  new ArrayList<>();
```

setupDrawing:

```
public void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
}
```

onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    for (Path path : currentMoveList) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }
    for (Path path : moveList) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }
}
```

onTouchEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            currentMoveList.add(drawPath);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            moveList.add(drawPath);
            drawPath = new Path();
            currentMoveList.clear();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

undo:

```
public void undo() {
    if (moveList.size() > 0) {
        undoList.add(moveList.remove(moveList.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
}
```

setColor:

```
public void setColor(String newColor) {
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```

PaintActivity.java

```
public void paintClicked(View view) {
    if (view != currPaint) {
        ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton) view;
        String color = view.getTag().toString();
        drawView.setColor(color);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
        currPaint = (ImageButton) view;
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.draw_btn) {
        drawView.setupDrawing();
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.undo_btn) {
        drawView.undo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем спустя пару дней поиска ответ был найден.
Рабочий пример можно посмотреть перейдя на [гитхаб](https://github.com/Dysgenix/Paint/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/paint)

Это

```
public void setColor(String newColor) {
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```

поменял на это

```
public void setColor (String color) {
    currentColor = Color.parseColor(color);
}
```